# Undistort the image in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I applied my calibration that depends on Radial Direct Alignment to an image, and figured out the extrinsic and intrinsic parameters. Now, I have to take this information and undistort the image back to get rid of the barrel distortion.

I did the following:

```py
dx = 0.00645
dy = 0.00645
#here we transform the focal length from mm into pixel 
Fx = F/dx
print('The Focal Length on X direction is: ', Fx, '\n')
#here the same in the y direction, for a perfect pinholecamera Fx = Fy
Fy = F/dy
print('The Focal Length on Y Direction is: ', Fy, '\n')
#here we introduce the camera matrix all in pixel
Camera_matrix = np.array([[Fx, 0, Cx], [0, Fy, Cy], [0, 0, 1]])

# Define distortion coefficients d
d = np.array([K1, K2, 0, 0, 0])
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# Generate new camera matrix from parameters
newcameramatrix, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(Camera_matrix, d,  (w,h),0)

# Generate look-up tables for remapping the camera image
mapx, mapy = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(Camera_matrix, d, None,   newcameramatrix, (w, h), 5)

# Remap the original image to a new image
newimg = cv2.remap(img, mapx, mapy, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

#view the original image
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
plt.imshow(img)
plt.title('Original Image', fontsize=16)
plt.show()

#view the new one
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
plt.imshow(newimg)
plt.title('The Calibrated Image', fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

Do you think that the result of the calibration is wrong? I felt that np change in the image that I applied the calibration to it?

Here is the image before calibration and the image after being calibrated:

[image: The image before calibration and the image after being calibrated]

Comment: Did you calibrate it with chessboard? with how many shots?

Comment: no not chessboard this millimeter paper, I took 63 calibration points

Comment: You need to take multiple images then calibrate the camera parameters, the more images, the more precision.